# While loop to check for duplicate characters

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

Okay, so I have the concept down of how to check for the duplicates, because i'm doing a project that includes not pushing multiple values onto a stack. So far my code is standard, save scanner to a string, save string to array, and then this while loop.

```
int c=0;
  while(counter < inAr.length)
  {
     String w1 = inAr[c];
     String w2 = inAr[c + 1];
     if(w1 != w2)
     {
        counter++;
        so.push(inAr[c]);
        c++;
        temp++;
     }
     else
     {
        counter++;
        c++;
     }
  }
```

Okay, so onto the problem. I'm getting an arrayindexoutofbounds for inAr[c + 1], but what i don't get is that inAr[1], inAr[2], and so on all hold values. If I replace the [c + 1] with a constant like [1] the program does fine and it works.... I'm so lost at this point, can anyone offer some help please

Comment: What do you think `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means?

Comment: What is counter initialized with?

Comment: Why are you talking about “duplicate characters” but comparing `String` *references*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the case when `c = inAr.length-1`.

At this point we will enter your while loop (as `c` and `counter` have the same value at each iteration, assuming initialization to 0)

`inAr[c+1]` is really `inAr[inAr.length]` which is always out of bounds.

FIX: Change your loop to `while(counter < inAr.length - 1)` or initialize counter to 1.

EDIT: You should also not compare Strings with `==` or `!=`. Your if-statement should be:

```
if(!w1.equals(w2))
```

But this isn't relevant to the actual question, just may cause problems later.

Answer (score 0):

it means that you are trying to access an element out of the array for eg. array length is 10 and you are trying to access index 11

Comment: Or even trying to access index 10 (which is a common confusion for beginners), because an array of length 10 has indices 0-9.

Answer (score 0):

your code is not breaking at the beginning of the loop, but rather the end of the loop.

`c` always equals `counter` when the condition is checked, and eventually, `counter` will be equal to `inArr.length` - 1.  and `c + 1` will be equal to `inArr.length`

Since arrays always start at index `0`(instead of `1`), you will always get an exception when you execute something like

```
mystr = inAr[inArr.length]
```

which you're effectively doing during what would be the last iteration of your `while` loop.